# Query to change the status of bulk magento orders

Tags: sql, status

I have a lot of Magento Orders with the wrong status 
Is there a way to change that bulk using a sql query?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to directly update order status from database, but yes you can change it directly to database. Make sure one thing that you change status as well as state of the order.

Like if it is in a status that is in processing state, and you want to move it to a status that is in new state, then you also need to change state to 'new'.

Query would be like this:

**For M2:**

```
UPDATE sales_order o SET o.state='new', o.`status`='pending' WHERE o.increment_id IN ('00000001','00000002',..);
UPDATE sales_order_grid og SET og.`status`='pending' WHERE og.increment_id IN ('00000001','00000002',..);
```

**For M1**

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order o SET o.state='new', o.`status`='pending' WHERE o.increment_id IN ('00000001','00000002',..);
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid og SET og.`status`='pending' WHERE og.increment_id IN ('00000001','00000002',..);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help It works, but I did as bellow and the status changed to "empty"

On the first line we are setting up the status and state, shouldn't I did the same on the second line?



UPDATE sales_flat_order o SET o.state='pending_payment', o.`status`='pagamento pendente' WHERE o.increment_id IN ('100288325');
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid og SET og.`status`='processing' WHERE og.increment_id IN ('100288325');

Comment: both grid and main table status and state should be same. And one more thing, there is no state `pending_payment`, it could be your status, make sure you are doing it correctly since you are doing it directly on database

Comment: hello, thanks for your help. It works now